# D3 removing previous bar chart on update of data

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, exit

I am having trouble removing bars from a bar chart when the data updates. I expected .exit().remove() to work. But when I update both bar charts are still there.

A minimum version is running on [gh-pages](https://shanegibney.github.io/d3-Draft-Update-Data/), you will need to use the dropdown menu to get it started. At the moment the first data file data1.json is not loading.

When a file loads only the bars associated with names that were in the previous render are displayed. When the same file in the drop down menu is clicked again the other bars appear. So the file has to be clicked on twice to display correctly.

If the initial render displays only the bars in common then this explains why it is blank when the page first loads, there is nothing in common.

Anyway, obviously this isn't the behaviour I am looking for.

And the code is on [github](https://github.com/shanegibney/d3-Draft-Update-Data) and on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/1r4nr9jk/)

```
          var newRects0 = g0.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data, function(d) {
              return d.name;
            });

          // newRects0.selectAll(".bar").remove();
          newRects0.enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('x', function(d, i) {
              return x(d.name);
            })
            // .attr('opacity', 0.33)
            .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
            .attr('y', height)
            .attr('height', 0)
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
            .style('fill', 'gray')
            .attr("class", function(d, i) {
              return "group" + i + " bar"
            });

          newRects0.exit().remove();

          newRects0.transition()
            .duration(100)
            .delay(function(d, i) {
              return i * 15
            })
            .attr("x", function(d) {
              return x(d.name);
            })
            .attr("y", function(d, i) {
              return y(d.clocktime);
            })
            .attr("height", function(d, i) {
              return height - y(d.clocktime)
            })
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth());
```

The x and y axes are changing correctly.

***UPDATE:***

I am now trying to use Bostock's [Update Pattern III](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234) The bars appear and then disappear after I think 750ms.

I have greatly simplified the code, it is now on [github](https://github.com/shanegibney/d3-Draft-Update-Data), [gh-pages](https://shanegibney.github.io/d3-Draft-Update-Data/), and [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/1r4nr9jk/4/).

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .container {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Data</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="defaultInput" value="one" href="#">data1.json</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="updateInput" value="two" href="#">data2.json</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="race_graph">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {
        top: 70,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 80
      },
      width = 1400 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%M:%S");
    var timeformat = d3.timeFormat("%M:%S");

    // set the domains and ranges
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
      .range([0, width])
      .padding([0.6]);

    // temporal y-scale
    var y = d3.scaleTime()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
      .ticks(7)
      .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%M:%S"));

    // Add main graph svg
    var svg = d3.select("#race_graph")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    // Add groups for main bar chart
    var g0 = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    function defaultFunction() {
      d3.json("data1.json", function(error, newdata) {
        if (error) throw error;
        data = newdata;

        data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.racetime = parseTime(d.racetime);
          d.handicap = parseTime(d.handicap);
          d.clocktime = parseTime(d.clocktime);
          d.place = +d.place;
          d.points = +d.points;
          d.raceplace = +d.raceplace;
          d.timeplace = +d.timeplace;
        })
        update();
      });
    }

    function updateFunction() {
      d3.json("data2.json", function(error, newdata) {
        if (error) throw error;
        data = newdata;
        data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.racetime = parseTime(d.racetime);
          d.handicap = parseTime(d.handicap);
          d.clocktime = parseTime(d.clocktime);
          d.place = +d.place;
          d.points = +d.points;
          d.raceplace = +d.raceplace;
          d.timeplace = +d.timeplace;
        })
        update(data);
      });
    }

    function update(err, newdata) {

      // set the domains
      x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.name
      }));

      // set domain temporal y-scale
      y.domain([parseTime('00:00'), d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.clocktime
      })]);

      // Add the X Axis
      svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
      svg.select(".x.axis").remove();
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left) + "," + (height + margin.top) + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-100,0)")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .style("font", "7px times")
        .attr("class", function(d, i) {
          return "groupText" + i + " xAxisText"
        })
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-75)");

      // Add the y axis on left
      svg.select(".y.axis").remove();
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left) + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .call(yAxis);

      var t = d3.transition()
        .duration(4000);

      // JOIN new data with old elements
      var newRects0 = g0.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data, function(d) {
          return d;
        });

      // EXIT old elements not present in new data
      newRects0.exit()
        .transition(t)
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return x(d.name);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return y(d.clocktime);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d, i) {
          return height - y(d.clocktime)
        })
        // .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .remove();

      // UPDATE old elements present in new data
      newRects0.attr("x", function(d) {
          return x(d.name);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return y(d.clocktime);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d, i) {
          return height - y(d.clocktime)
        })
        // .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .style('fill', 'gray');

      // ENTER new elements present in new data
      newRects0.enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return x(d.name);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return y(d.clocktime);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d, i) {
          return height - y(d.clocktime)
        })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .style('fill', 'gray')
        .attr("class", function(d, i) {
          return "group" + i + " bar"
        });

    }; //closes update() function

    document.getElementById("defaultInput")
      .onclick = defaultFunction;
    document.getElementById("updateInput")
      .onclick = updateFunction;
    defaultFunction();
  </script>
</body>
```

Thanks,

Comment: You have to provide more code than that. *How* are you updating the chart? What is the data? For what you said, I suspect that `g0` itself is a **new** selection every time you update the chart.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this, there is gh-pages demo at https://shanegibney.github.io/d3-Draft-Update-Data/ you need to use the dropdown menu and the code is at https://github.com/shanegibney/d3-Draft-Update-Data

Comment: @GerardoFurtado g0 is outside the update() function so that selection is only made once. Does it need to be made every time the data changes?

Comment: Here is a running jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/1r4nr9jk/ again it is necessary to use the dropdown menu.

Comment: I do have an example working https://github.com/shanegibney/D3-v4-Dropdown-Change-Dataset-JSON but just don't seem to be able to apply the same this situation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The 1st line of my draw function is:

```
d3.selectAll("svg").remove();
```

This clears the svg and all the associated objects before creating a new svg (dependent on window size) and updating it with the new data being imported.

You could select the rectangles you want to remove individually, but if the axis are changing in response to the new data, it might be worth just removing everything and drawing the axis' again.

Edit: I think the confusion is in the "defaultFunction"/"updateFunction".

```
 document.getElementById("defaultInput")
  .onclick = defaultFunction;
document.getElementById("updateInput")
  .onclick = updateFunction;
defaultFunction();
```

for "updateInput", both data1.json and data2.json are being loaded by updateFunction and defaultFunction respectively.

if you can separate out the chart function, then have

```
function input1() {
d3.json("data1.json", function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        return console.error(error);
    } else
 update(data);
})}

 function input2() {
d3.json("data2.json", function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        return console.error(error);
    } else
 update(data);
})}

function update (data){
remove old data;
parse new data;
make graph...
}
```

That should clear it up.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. The axes are fine and I would prefer not to change them. I understand that it would be simpler to remove the svg, its objects and bound data but I would as much as possible like to update data. However I tried using d3.selectAll("svg").remove(); which means I have to select it again. I just can't figure out why .exit() doesn't remove the unused data. I thought that's what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I think it depends on how the data is being added, I thought the dropdown was somehow adding the 2 datasets together, but I now see that it's starting with all the data when you select data1.json. But for some reason data2.json seems fine...

Comment: Nope, still confused, so there should be 10 rectangles after you select either dataset? But for some reason, changing between the datasets, only the 3 or so that are in both (SD, DK and SL) are shown. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes that is exactly the problem. Thanks for looking at it. I need to play with .exit .remove a bit more thanks

Comment: I just saw now you edited the answer. I'll try that solution.

Comment: When you say "remove old data" should I use .exit() or .exit().remove() ? Should i be removing the rect or anything with .bar also?

Comment: I have greatly simplified the code and updated the question to reflect my attempt to use Bostock's Update Pattern III. There are links to github, a gh-pages demo and jsFiddle. I'm really stuck with this problem

Comment: It's looking like it's working now, at least there's 10 or so bars after each update. What I do is update the data array (data in the example I used), so the new data just overwrites the old. But I'm not trying any transitions, or parsing the data. I completely redraw my visualisation, which probably makes it a bit simpler for me.

Comment: Just now I got it to make all the transitions correctly. It is working, thanks https://shanegibney.github.io/d3-Draft-Update-Data/

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out Bostock's example [Update Pattern III](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234) and have applied this to the bar-chart.

Here is the code on [github](https://github.com/shanegibney/D3-v4-Bar-Chart-Update-Pattern) and a demo on [gh-pages](https://shanegibney.github.io/D3-v4-Bar-Chart-Update-Pattern/).

The stages in this pattern are,

- JOIN the new data with old elements
- EXIT old elements not present in new data
- UPDATE old elements present in new data
- ENTER new elements present in new data